# Math mode in chemformula

Tags: math-mode, chemformula

How do i use math mode in chemformula?
The first example works, including the sub- and superscript. In the second example the subscripts don't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions}}
\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
X -> Y  &\hfill &   \text{because\ $E=m_{x}c^2$}
\end{reactions}
\begin{reactions}
A + B &->[$E_{a,1}$] AB \\
A + K + B &->[$E_{a,2}$] AK ->[$E_{a,3}$] AB + P
\end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a `reactions` environment, `_` changes its meaning; you can use `\sb` in its place. For `^` there is `\sp`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={reactions}}
\begin{document}
\begin{reactions}
X -> Y  &\hfill &   \text{because\ $E=m\sb{x}c^2$}
\end{reactions}
\begin{reactions}
A + B &->[$E\sb{a,1}$] AB \\
A + K + B &->[$E\sb{a,2}$] AK ->[$E\sb{a,3}$] AB + P
\end{reactions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that command `\sb`. Is it always an identical backup to `_`?

Comment: @Wulfram Yes, unless some devious package changes it.

Answer (score 3):

When using `chemformula` it is important to know that spaces separate different parts inside `\ch{..}` and – as a consequence – inside a `reaction` environment. This means `->[ $E_{a,1}$ ]` will work.  There is only one thing else to keep in mind: `chemformula` per default inserts some space before a math part. (I am not convinced any more  this is the best default behaviour, but…)

BTW: it also doesn't make much sense (IMHO it's actually wrong) to write a text part within `\ch{...}` with `\text`.  The recommended way in `chemformula` is escaping text with `"..."`: `"because\ $E=m_{x}c^2$"`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  modules={reactions} ,
  formula = chemformula ,
  chemformula/math-space = 0pt
}
\begin{document}

\begin{reactions}
  X -> Y  & & "because\ $E=m_{x}c^2$"
\end{reactions}

\begin{reactions}
  A + B &->[ $E_{a,1}$ ] AB \\
  A + K + B &->[ $E_{a,2}$ ] AK ->[ $E_{a,3}$ ] AB + P
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Well, I used `\text{}` because i am used to do so in equations resp. i the `\begin{align}`environment (is that wrong?). It's just a made up example here, I don't usually put text in reactions...

Comment: If I am already here - how can i make labels over arrows that are more than one line? Didn't find an example in the documentation. `\\ `, `\newline`and `\linebreak` don't work.

Comment: @Wulfram `\text` is a command by `amsmath` for placing text in math mode which matches the surrounding text. `chemformula` OTOH explicitly mentions its “escaping” mechanism with `"..."` in its manual.

Comment: @Wulfram maybe `\newcommand*\stack[2][c]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}` and `\ch{A ->[\stack{x\\y}] B}`